# Upload image file using slack API files.upload method

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, guzzle, slack-api

The following code seems to work, but the Slack API saves the file a plain text.

```
protected function upload($file)
{
    $client = $this->guzzle;

    if (!$token) {
        $token = env('SLACK_TOKEN');
    }

    $response = $client->request('POST', env('SLACK_API') . "/files.upload?token=$token", [
        'form_params' => [
            'name' => $file->getFilename(),
            'content' => File::get($file->getRealPath()),
            'filename' => $file->getFilename(),
            'filetype' => 'image',
            'channels' => "#_test",
        ]
    ]);


    return json_decode((string)$response->getBody());
}
```

When I use the guzzle `multipart` post, I get the error: `'no_file_data'` I feel like I am missing something.

Is there a way to upload images or non-text files using the `files.upload` method in the Slack API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost as soon as I posted this question, I realized that I was formatting the array incorrectly on the `multipart` post in guzzle.

This seems to work:

```
$response = $this->guzzle->post(env('SLACK_API') . "/files.upload?token=$token", 
  ['multipart' => 
    [
        [
            'name' => 'filename',
            'contents' => $file->getClientOriginalName()
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'file',
            'contents' => fopen($file,'r')
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'channels',
            'contents' => '#_test'
        ]
    ]
  ]);
```